# How to add top margin to web view application?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I have a web view application which has a top menu bar. It all was working properly until Iphone X. 
As you can see it has a top menu bar, and it needs some space on top to clear the speaker of the iphone X. Is there any way to make the web view smaller? I tried with constraints but I couldnt quite get it working.

Can I make the webview smaller at the top and add some background color/gradient or something? As you can see in the picture when I scroll down I can see content by the sides of the speaker and above the menu bar (which should be at the very top of the webview)

[image: Iphone Example]

This is the start of my class definition:

```
    public partial class WebViewController : UIViewController
{

    LoadingOverlay loadPop;
    bool loadPopStatus = false;

    public override bool PrefersStatusBarHidden(){
        return true;
    }

    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone
    {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    protected WebViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.

    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
        var username = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("username");
        var login_token = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("login_token");
        var refresh_token = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("refresh_token");
        var company_name = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("company");

        // Intercept URL loading to handle native calls from browser
        WebView.ShouldStartLoad += HandleShouldStartLoad;
        //Change status bar background
        //WebView.ScrollView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(20, 20, 20, 20);
        //WebView.ScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        //WebView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

        //WebView.ScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.Never;
```

You can see some of my failed attempts commented out in my webviewcontroller definition. I tried insents and other stuff

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/updating-xamarin-ios-apps-for-the-iphone-x/

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt lets me resize the layout area in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the correct constraints to this WebView to make it smaller. The top and bottom constraints of the WebView should connect to the `TopLayoutGuide` and `BottomLayoutGuide`, so that iPhone X's "head" and "foot" will not be used.

I will show my Storyboard screenshot for these four constraints below:

[image]

But use code to create the constraints may be more clearly:

```
// Disable this property to enable autolayout
MyWebView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

var leadConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MyWebView, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, 1.0f, 0);
var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MyWebView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 0);
var trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MyWebView, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1.0f, 0);
var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.Create(MyWebView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BottomLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 0);

View.AddConstraints(new NSLayoutConstraint[] { leadConstraint, topConstraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint });
```

This will make a space at the top and bottom of the iPhone X which we should not use and we just call it **safe area**.

If you want to make it look like a component of the WebView, you can set the `View`'s Background color the same as your WebView's. It seems purple red from your screenshot. Maybe like this:

```
View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help but it doesnt quite works. I tried that right after my  
bool HandleShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
        {
But it just makes the whole screen black. (Without the purple background color line)

Comment: I made a simple project with only one WebView [here](https://github.com/landl0526/SingleWebViewDemo.git). You can change the url to yours then test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it does not work in my application. I tested yours and it works but not in mine. Maybe I have some weird setting setup somewhere. 
I tried creating a div with javascript on every pageload there  (top 0 left 0 fixed). And it still shows on top of my grey menu bar rather than under the speaker. Ill still mark your solution as the answer because it seems it will be the solution for a lot of people. Just not for me X)

Comment: You can try to create a blank project to test that. Or try to upload a sample with this issue, let's analyze it.